# Extract lines without no spaces into a text file through a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Thanks in advance for your valuable inputs
Through a `batch` file,I'm trying to `read line by line a text file` **except** those starting with space.

I have tried this:

for /f  "eol=^"" " %%x in (file.txt) do echo. %%x>out
What I have done is also reading lines from file begining with spaces.

I also tried this:
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('find /v ^" " %1')  do (
   echo.%%a
pause
console output is empty.

Assume that my file looks like this one:

Draw something

***************** STEP 1 ****************

Draw something else

============================
    ...............................

For this example, I have to read one line after another one

Draw something

Draw something else

Any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that's an easy one!

```
findstr /v /b /c:" " <file.txt
```

finds lines **EXCEPT** `/v` **begin with** `/b` **the literal string `" "`** `/c:" "`

see `findstr /?` from the prompt for docco...

Comment: Wonderful it worked! I had forgotten /b. Thank you very much Peter

Answer (score 0):

You found the correct FOR /F option, but you failed to find the correct usage. All lines that begin with the EOL character are skipped, and the very next character after `EOL=` is always the EOL character. You simply want a space after the equal.

You also want to preserve the entire line, so you need to set DELIMS to nothing.

```
for /f  "eol= delims=" %%x in (file.txt) do echo. %%x>out
```

Peter Wright's FINDSTR solution is a simpler way to eliminate lines that begin with space. But I'm assuming you want to do additional processing with each line that does not begin with space.